# How to run postgresql sql script file in helm

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to run create.sql file in postgresql in helm and Creating a temporary pod to connect to database.(part of the command is taken from the suggestion after helm install)

I have below commands to create helm and connect to database.

```
global:
  postgresql:
    auth:
      # Added below credentials for testing
      postgresPassword: "postgresqladmin"
      username: "admin"
      password: "admin"
      database: "postgresqlDB"
containerPorts:
  postgresql: 5432
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: bitnami/postgresql
  tag: 15.4.0-debian-11-r10
  digest: ""
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  debug: false
```

Here are the command commands:

```
helm upgrade --install postgresql -f values.yaml bitnami/postgresql
kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' \
--image bitnami/postgresql --env="PGPASSWORD=admin" && \
kubectl cp ./create.sql postgresql-client:/create.sql && \
psql --host postgresql -U admin -d postgresqlDB -p 5432 -f /create.sql
```

but with the above command stops after --env and shows logs with error

```
The POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD environment variable is empty or not set. Set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes to allow the container to be started with blank passwords. This is recommended only for development.
```

How to write a command to execute sql script file

I tried creating table like this currently

```
kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i \
        --restart='Never' --image "docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:15.4.0-debian-11-r10" \
        --env="PGPASSWORD=admin" --command -- \
        psql --host postgresql -U admin -d postgresqlDB -p 5432 "CREATE TABLE my_table ( \
       id serial PRIMARY KEY,\
       field VARCHAR(255)\
    );"
```

Comment: If you're going to run `psql` locally, can you `kubectl port-forward` a connection to the database container?

Comment: It works fine locally, I want to run it on k8s